# How come django-compressor still output a file when memcached is used?

Tags: django-compressor

Is it correct behaviour for django-compressor to still output the compressed file in the COMPRESS_ROOT folder even when Memcached is enabled?

In the docs it says:

> For production sites it is strongly recommended to use a real cache backend such as memcached to speed up the checks of compressed files.

My cache in Django is set up correctly and working.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        }
}
```

What I'm seeing is, with memcached enabled, if I delete the STATIC_ROOT folder, django-compressor does not regenerate the js/css files anymore. Anyone else see this bahaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problems.   To fix it, I created a small django management command in my django app to clear memcache, which I run during deployment.

I suppose if you rely on memcache for many things, you might want to be more fine-grained, but for us blowing away the whole cache is fine.

Code as follows:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError 
import getpass

class Command(BaseCommand):   help = 'Flush the memcache (or whatever the default caching system is)'

  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if ("flush_all" in dir(cache._cache)):
      cache._cache.flush_all()
      print "Cache Flush Done."
    else:
      print "No-op ... this cache type has no flush"
```